# Why does jquery code not working on the server but works on my PC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, internet-explorer

I am struggling with a problem of  an html page not rendering the same way on the hosting company's server compared with my PC. This is how it looks in Chrome: http://www.i-learn-french.com/html5/audiocards.html
On my PC in IE it looks a little different, but preserves most of its functionality, while on the server it looks like the jquery code doesn't work.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var link = document.createElement('link');
   var linkchrome = document.getElementById('#chromelink');
   link.id = 'newlink';
   link.rel = 'stylesheet';
   link.type = 'text/css';
   link.href = '../ie/iestyles.css';
   link.media = 'all';
   $(link).appendTo(head);
   head.removeChild($linkchrome);
}
```

Why does this code work on my PC and not on the server? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `jQuery.browser` "was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead." http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: also is it possible you have a newer version of IE than the server? I know some companies don't run windows updates on IE browser on server (since no one's cruising the web from that box).

Comment: Ensure you have included the library of jQuery on your PC and that the path to it is ok etc

Comment: Just wanted to add that the css formatting also renders differently. In IE on my PC it there is very difference, but on the server it is all distorted.

Comment: css and jquery issues would almost certainly dictate that this is a file path error

Comment: Have you put your code into an `$(document).ready(function(){...});`? Because if not, the document is not fully loaded when your script gets  executed!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if IE is running in compatibility mode when accessing the application deployed to the server.  IE has a habit of displaying intranet sites in compatibility mode.  You can check this setting in IE by going to *Tools -> Compatibility View settings*.  Look at the value of the checkbox labeled *Display intranet sites in Compatibility View*.